# "every commutative ring has a maximal ideal" => "every ring does"?

Tags: ring-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is known that Choice is equivalent to the statement "every nonzero ring has a maximal ideal".

But, if I'm reading [this abstract](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.19940400405) correctly (I don't have access to the full paper), it is also equivalent to the more specific statement that only specifies commutative rings.

Is there a proof from "maximal ideals in commutative rings" to "maximal ideals in general rings", that doesn't pass though Zorn's lemma, Choice, etc., and stays entirely (or at least mostly) in the algebraic domain?

I thought about using the abelianization of the ring, which has a maximal ideal, but in general, maximal ideals don't pull back to maximal ideals, and to get the desired conclusion, this has to work for any ring.

Does anyone know of such an argument?

Comment: I personally am an adept of a school of mathematical formalism that has the axiom of choice inbuilt as a fundamental syntactic mechanism (so that it is available without even needing to be officially postulated as an axiom), so I cannot make too many observations on the equivalence you seek to investigate but I would to like to ask something for clarification: maximal ideals of *what kind* in an arbitrary ring? Maximal *left* ideals? Maximal *right* ideals? Maximal *bilateral* ideals?

Comment: Maximal ideals do pull back to maximal ideals under quotient maps.  The problem with using the abelianization is that it might be zero.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh right, surjectivity is enough. Been a while since I've thought about ideals, to be honest.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ they all have the same implications for commutative rings, and this is purely a curiosity question, so, "whichever is more interesting", I suppose.

Comment: I'm not sure if [tag:axiom-of-choice] is right here. You're asking how to avoid set theory altogether and find an algebraic proof for an implication. What I can suggest is that you try and fuse the proofs. See where choice is needed in the latter, and obtain that choice from the former. Then merge the proofs to an "algebraic" construction.

Comment: @Henry Swanson It is perhaps not going to be very helpful in your inquiry, but I wanted to remark that the classical series of results according to which any nonzero ring admits maximal left/right/bilateral ideals fits inside the more general setting of *closure systems*: consider an *algebraic* closure system $\mathscr{K}$ on a set $A$, such that $A$ is a finitely generated $\mathscr{K}$-substructure and there are other members of $\mathscr{K}$ apart from $A$ (in other words, there are *proper* $\mathscr{K}$-substructures) *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Henry Swanson *(cont.)* Then any proper $\mathscr{K}$-substructure is included in a *maximal* such substructure, as it can be easily shown under the given conditions that the set $\mathscr{K} \setminus \{A\}$ orderd by inclusion is inductive. This is the essence of the phenomena encountered in algebra, the commutativity of the underlying algebraic structure not playing any role.